# TinyMCE - Custom Button for inserting a specific template

Tags: tinymce, prestashop, customization, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop. I have made several templates. Is it possible to prepare a button that will insert the selected template?
For example, I have 4 templates and I want to make 4 buttons.
the first button inserts the first template.
the second button inserts the second template and so on.
I tried to use this code in the file `\js\admin\tinymce.inc.js` but my new button is not displaying :(

```
    toolbar2: 'customInsertButton',
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.ui.registry.addButton('customInsertButton', {
        text: 'My Button',
        onAction: function (_) {
          editor.insertContent('My button works!');
        }
      });
    },
```

Perhaps Prestashop has some limited version of this editor?
I ask because for example it is possible to add templates. but I would like to be able to insert them faster, with one button...

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE itself already has a template plugin:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/template/

Have you considered using that functionality?

Comment: I have templates made. But I wanted to make it easier to insert them. I am interested in a button with which I will insert a specific HTML code exactly as in the example above. [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/typesoftoolbarbuttons/#)

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution. It is possible by adding a custom plugin.
Everything is beautifully described on the TinyMCE website :
[https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/](https://%20https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/)
then we modify tinymce.inc.js and add plugin support and a defined button in the toolbar.